# How to fix "but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint ."

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

`myFunc` can take either `string` or `number` But since argument is defined as T gives error when a string is passed.

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[],
  onValueChange: (vals: T[]) => void;
}

export const myComponent = <T extends string | number>(props: Props<T>) => {

  const {
    items = [],
    onValueChange
  } = props;

  const myFunc = (item: T) => {
    //do something
    console.log(item);
    onValueChange([item])
  }

  items.map(item => myFunc(item));

  myFunc('test');

}
```

Error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
```

How to fix this?

See in: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQD5kBvAKGWWEgFscAuZAgbQF0AaS5DEANTgAbAK4QAwgAs4IAOYQmACgBuQxs3YBKZAF4SSjMAAmAbnIBfcuQgAPLBihhkCXjke0AnmIy07ICOB1kQmQbSBBDHGRXKFAZZAAfZBBhWgAjaCIFLExcJnRsfGItXTJLKmcQV1KqKhoIekD2LhqefiFRSWk5bjNA7ILTbgqqjwAxYRAEQIU62iYCYpIKFoB6FcMMKO8IMAlY7nKXDEEIADpBDBkZug1TFt4BEXEpWQgFFlm2DR6y6jocU60OBYa71HQkMYTBCg2gaW6-SGTBQAckgrmR8PMQA)

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect this to work or what the goal is; if you call `myComponent()` with a `Props<number>` input, then `myFunc("test")` is definitely wrong, because `T` is `number` and `"test"` is not a `number`. ([example](https://tsplay.dev/mpDv6m))  I'm not sure why you want `myComponent` to be generic at all.   I wish I had more explanation about what you're trying to accomplish so I could suggest a fix that actually works in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler message is actually quite clear: You have constrained the `myComponent` function to only accept props with a resolved type such as `string`, `number`, `string|number`, or `never`. You have also used the same constraint placed on that function to also restrict what types `myFunc` can receive (which at this point is whatever was passed into `myComponent`).

The problem the compiler is trying to draw your attention to is that if `myComponent` is called with `Props<number>`, `T` becomes restricted to only `number`, which is also what `myFunc` will be restricted to, therefore if you do `myFunc('test');` you may be violating the current constraint on `myFunc` which is that it only accepts `number` types, not `string`.

---

If you do not wish to adhere to this safeguard, you can shake off the restraints and allow both `myFunc` and `myComponent` to become contractually independent of each other, which allows you do what you originally wished to do:

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[],
  onValueChange: (vals: T[]) => void;
}

type ItemType = string | number;

export const myComponent = (props: Props<ItemType>) => {
  const {
    items = [],
    onValueChange
  } = props;

  const myFunc = (item: ItemType) => {
    //do something
    console.log(item);
    onValueChange([item])
  }

  items.map(item => myFunc(item));

  myFunc('test');
}
```

Another way:

```
interface Props<T> {
  items: T[],
  onValueChange: (vals: T[]) => void;
}

export const myComponent: React.FC<Props<string | number>> = ({items = [], onValueChange}) => {

  const myFunc = (item: string | number) => {
    //do something
    console.log(item);
    onValueChange([item])
  }

  items.map(item => myFunc(item));

  myFunc('test');

  return {};
}
```

Comment: no explanation? these solutions may work but that's it, it's an attempt to make typescript accept your code without understanding the reason for the error message. in this case generics are really not necessary and you should explain it rather them just throwing in code

Comment: @EliavLouski you're right. I've added some explanations. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

If it suites your case you can make the type constraint a bit more strict:

```ts
export const myComponent = <T extends Props<string | number>>(props: T) => {

  const {
    items = [],
    onValueChange
  } = props;

  const myFunc = (item: string | number) => {
    //do something
    console.log(item);
    onValueChange([item])
  }

  items.map(item => myFunc(item));

  myFunc('test');
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WK88ow)

Comment: I simplified it too much. Question updated.  Also now I realize that there is something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Nice, The trick is to detach the function argument from the generic type.

Comment: The problem with `T extends string | number` and using such a `T` inside `myFunc` is that there are literal types in typescript. For example, _literal type_ `not-test` perfectly extends `string | number` **but** you cannot call `myFunc('test')` because `T` shoud be of the literal type `non-test`, but you're trying to call the function with `test`. So the error tells you exactly that. While 'test` can be assigned to the constraint of `T` (i.e. `string | number`) the `T` could be instantiated witn incompatible type, for example literal type `non-test`.